# Call main program function from loaded shared object lib

Tags: c, plugins, shared-libraries, visibility

Is it possible to call a function from the main program inside a shared object library?

I currently have no code, but I think about a plugin system for a software I wrote, and want to know if this is possible, because of security reasons. Some Pseudocode:

```
/* main program */
void disturbe() {
    /*some bad stuff, just the main program should be able to call*/
}

main()
    lib = load_library("foo.so");
    lib->function();
}

/* foo.so */

void function() {
    disturbe();
}
```

Comment: How can foo.so gets compiled if has an undefined function inside?

Comment: Well, that's not the point. I want to know if this is possible in _any_ way, because of security reasons. How, doesn't intrest me so much!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say yes: As `function()` had been loaded into the process' address space it *could* access the process' functions, at least "somehow".

To keep things strictly seperated use different processes.

Comment: Sounds complicated. I'll mark this as correct answer, if I do not get a more detailed one. Hope, you're fine with this! Edit: (double negation error :-) )

Comment: @musicmatze: Sure, do as you like. Anyway, besides accepting an answer you can also simple upvote it if you like it ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is problematic because when you compile the library, it will have an unresolved link to disturbe().  Instead, if you need to have the library call functions in the main module, it's better to have pointers to stub functions in the library, then set those pointers with an initialization call from the main module to the library at runtime.  We use this method a lot in our commercial product for our "callback" functions.  Here is an example from our code:

In library.h:

```
typedef bool (*pbWMC)(DCwfile *, unc);

// stub functions for uninitialized pointers 
static bool StubbWMC(DCwfile *df, unc uch);

// variables set by Init()
static pbWMC WriteMacroChar;
```

In library.cpp:

```
// callback functions
pbWMC DCmacr::WriteMacroChar = StubbWMC;

// stub functions for uninitialized function pointers
bool DCmacr::StubbWMC(DCwfile *df, unc uch)
{
    return false;
}

// initializer called from main module
void DCmacr::InitMacroModule(DCwfile *df, pbWMC fwmc)
{
    if (df)
        DestFile = df;
    if (fwmc)
        WriteMacroChar = fwmc;
}
```

In main module.cpp:

```
// call to initializer
DCmacr::InitMacroModule(wf, WriteMacroChar);

// function called by library
bool HTMwr::WriteMacroChar(DCwfile *df, unc uch)
{
    HTMwfile *wf = (HTMwfile *) df;

    if (uch == 183) {  // bullet
        wf->putSpec(uch);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This design allows us to specify different callback functions for each invocation of the library, making the code truly modular.  We use C++, but the same design works as is in C.
HTH!